# How can i get date format for add to calender google link

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, date, google-calendar-api

I want to generate a google calendar joining link through javascript function. For this i need a specific date format that google calendar understands. e.g. Below is the google calendar link

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20201210T093000Z/20201210T103000Z&text=Test+Test&location&details=&sf=true

In this link the date format required is somewhat like this 20201210T093000Z. This is the start date for the event and after / is the end date of the event.

Suppose i have a date 12/4/2020(dd/mm/yyyy) and time 4:00pm. how can i convert it to above date format.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a `Date` object

This is the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on it. For example, this snippet will produce a date in the format "20201210T093000Z" (depending on the platform).

```js
let now = new Date
console.log(now)
```

So to create a new `Date` object with your time you could do this:

```js
let myDate = new Date()
myDate.setYear(2020)
myDate.setMonth(3) // Note it has to be one less than the actual month
myDate.setDate(12)
myDate.setHours(16)
myDate.setMinutes(0)
myDate.setSeconds(0)
myDate.setMilliseconds(0)

console.log(myDate)
```